# Counting no. of dropdownlists inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="myDiv">    
    <select id="ddl1" name="31">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3" selected="selected">Three</option>
    </select>

    <select id="ddl2" name=32>
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>
    </select>    
</div>
```

Thats my div. The number of dropdowns inside this div vary. What I want is this in a string:-

```
31,3||32,2
```

The above is name attribute value of dropdowns, 2nd number after comma is the "value" of the selected option and values of both dropdownlists are separated by pipe symbol. The dropdowns can be 3 and 4 in number too. How can I acheive this in jquery?

Answer (score 4):

A little something like this:

```
var selects = [];
$("#myDiv select").each(function() {
    selects.push(this.name + "," + $(this).val());
});
var output = selects.join("||");
```

Where the [`.each()` method](http://api.jquery.com/each/) is used to iterate through all the select elements and push their name and current value into the `selects` array, then the array `.join()` method is used to turn the array into a string using `"||"` as the separator.

Comment: will it matter if my dropdowns are enclosed in different divs inside the main div "myDiv" ?? its returning blank result to me

Comment: Where are you running the above code from? If it runs immediately on page load you need to include it in a script block _after_ all the divs/selects _or_ inside a $(document).ready() handler. $("#myDiv select") says "find _all_ select elements that are _descendants_ of #myDiv" - not only direct children - so it will be fine if "myDiv" contains other divs and they in turn contain your selects. As long as you only have one element on the page with the id "myDiv" - id needs to be unique.

Answer (score 2):

try this snippet:

```
var output = [];
$('#myDiv select').each(function() {
   output.push([this.name, $(this).val()].join(','));
});

console.log(output.join('||'));
```

Comment: will it matter if my dropdowns are enclosed in different divs inside the main div "myDiv" ?? its returning blank result to me

Comment: of course it matters: you should have only one element with that id. (you asked for dropdown contained inside a div). Anyway try simply using `$('select')` instead of `$('#myDiv select')` (you will pick every select on your page)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var values = [];
$('#myDiv select').each(function() {
  values.push($(this).attr('name') + ',' + $(this).val());
});
var result = values.join('||');
```

Comment: will it matter if my dropdowns are enclosed in different divs inside the main div "myDiv" ?? its returning blank result to me

Answer (score 0):

```
    var val = "";
    $("select").each(function(){
        val += $(this).attr("name") + "," + $("option:selected",this).val()+ "||";
    })
if(val != "")
val = val.substring(0, val.length - 2);
        console.log(val);
```

Comment: this will end up like this -> 31,3||32,2||

Comment: it will be so simple to eliminate the last 2 characters of the string